# PHP MongoDB - String search - Case insensitive and special characters

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I'm using below query to find the duplicate record.

```
$doc = $db->collection->findOne(array('field' => new MongoRegex("/^$value/i")));

if (isset($doc) === false) {
    $db->collection->insert(array('field' => $value));
}
```

This works fine until a special character comes like "(", ")", and might be some more. How should I change my query to work in these cases?

Comment: using `preg_quote`

Comment: `$db->collection->findOne(array('field' => new MongoRegex("/^" . preg_quote($value) . "/i")));` I tried like this. This is also not working.

Comment: Try replacing `preg_quote($value)` with `preg_quote($value, '/')`

Comment: So, did you try to use that suggestion above?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did not see the notification. It works perfect. Thank you both for the help. Can anyone of you post this as answer? So i'll accept and it might be useful for others.