# how to do case insensitive search of a string with special charater in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

how to do case insensitive search of a string with special charater in `mongodb`?
eg: string be like `srg_at(01)`
 `new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^".string."$","i");` is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [String search - Case insensitive and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277719/php-mongodb-string-search-case-insensitive-and-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

In your example it may be:

```
db.somedb.find({name:  /^.$string.$/i });
```